# copy files based on matching symbol

Tags: python, linux, bash, for-loop, sed

i have a directory that contains thousand of files.However i have a list that contain file names of the same directory. I want to copy the files which contain star mark * at the end from the list.

List is

```
2016-05-23-0145-30S.INMME_012*
2016-07-12-0546-26S.INMME_006
2016-07-17-2033-16S.INMME_003
2016-07-19-1307-57S.INMME_003
2016-08-17-1649-12S.INMME_006*
2016-09-03-1151-03S.INMME_003
2016-10-21-1240-02S.INMME_006*
2016-10-21-1310-38S.INMME_006
2016-10-23-0016-39S.INMME_006
2016-10-23-0859-50S.INMME_006
```

So i want to copy     `2016-05-23-0145-30S.INMME_012*      2016-08-17-1649-12S.INMME_006*    2016-10-21-1240-02S.INMME_006*` to separate directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
def copy_file_to_another_location(inputpath, outputpath, filename):
   if not os.path.exists(outputpath):
      os.makedirs(outputpath)
   shutil.copy(str(os.path.join(inputpath, filename)).replace("\n", "").replace("*", ""), str(os.path.join(outputpath, filename)).replace("\n", "").replace("*", ""))
   print("Copying: " + str(os.path.join(inputpath, filename)).replace("\n", ""))

inputpath = r'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\tada\\in'
outputpath = r'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\tada\\out'
file = open("asd.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
files_list = file.readlines()
for file in files_list:
   if "*" in str(file):
      copy_file_to_another_location(inputpath, outputpath, file)
```

NOTE: This script will make sure to keep the folder structure from input location to output location (ex: `inputlocation/some_folder/2016-10-23....` will be copied to `outputlocation/some_folder/2016-10-23...`)

Comment: Sir i have thousand of files quite difficult to edit file list...can you please suggest in a automatic way

Comment: You don't have to edit the list, what are you talking about? What format is your list, is it saved in a .txt file, csv file?

Comment: There you go. I've edited the script. This will read the .txt file and save all lines from it to a list, than check each line from the list if contains a "*"

Comment: print("Copying: " + str(os.path.join(inputpath, filename)))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, on the line above the `print` one, there should be one `)` more at the end. I've just added it. Also make sure on line `for file in file_list` to change to `for file in files_list`. I've forgot to add the **s** at the end of `file` word. (edited this one too)

Comment: for file in file_list:
NameError: name 'file_list' is not defined

Comment: read the comment above. Change from `file_list` to `files_list`. Also you can copy again the script, I've updated it with the change

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'2016-05-23-0145-30S.INMME_012*\n' but i have 2016-05-23-0145-30S.INMME_012* in the directory

Comment: Try again with this one. I've forgot about the "\n" added by `readlines()`.

Comment: One question. Is the star in the real files name too? Otherwise, you should put `.replace("*", "")` after each existing `replace()` function

Comment: it would be easier if I knew this. Okay, last update on this. The problem was that the "*" was missing from the real filename, but it was looking for it. Now script should remove that before trying to copy the file.